# How do I apply proportionate class change on mousemove?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a five star rating system with the following html:

```
<div class="rate-small rate0"></div>
```

If it were to read `rate-small rate50` that would indicate all five stars highlighted, similarly `rate-small rate25` would indicate 2.5 stars.

What I want to be able to do is when the user hovers over the stars, they proper amount of stars highlight as the user moves the mouse along the stars. So if they were hovering over the second star, stars one and two would be highlighted. If they were on the fifth star, all the stars would be highlighted. A click then records the rating.

My Jquery seemed to be working just fine but now the coordinates seem to be completely off when I console.log for reference. Ultimately I am having trouble grasping how to tell jquery when to change the class withe mousemove. The coordinates seem to be right one time and then not the next. Ultimately I don't like the way I have it set up, obviously it doesn't work real well and it seems like there should be a better way to proportionately apply the hover classes without using such static coordinates, but I just can't quite figure out the best way to approach:

```
var rate={
    start: function(){

       $('body').on('mousemove','div.rate-small',function(e){
       var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
       var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
       //console.log(y);
        if(x>'534' && x<'662'){
            rate.makeBold();
            if(x>'540' && x<'550'){
             $(this).attr('class','rate-small rate5')   
            }
            else if(x>'550' && x<'560'){
             $(this).attr('class','rate-small rate10')  
            }
            else if(x>'560' && x<'570'){
             $(this).attr('class','rate-small rate15')  
            }
            else if(x>'570' && x<'580'){
             $(this).attr('class','rate-small rate20')  
            }
            else if(x>'580' && x<'590'){
             $(this).attr('class','rate-small rate25')  
            }
            else if(x>'590' && x<'600'){
             $(this).attr('class','rate-small rate30')  
            }
            else if(x>'600' && x<'610'){
             $(this).attr('class','rate-small rate35')  
            }
            else if(x>'610' && x<'620'){
             $(this).attr('class','rate-small rate40')  
            }
            else if(x>'620' && x<'630'){
             $(this).attr('class','rate-small rate45')  
            }
            else if(x>'630' && x<'660'){
             $(this).attr('class','rate-small rate50')  
            }
          }
       }).on('mouseleave','div.rate-small', function(){
             $(this).attr('class','rate-small rate0');
             rate.removeBold(); 

       }).on('click','div.rate-small', function(){
           var rateId = ($(this).attr('id'));
           var rateClass = ($(this).attr('class'));
           var rateNum = rateClass.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')
           rate.sendrate(rateId,rateNum)
       })

  },
}
```

Notes: This code was working just fine, but now when I console.log the y coordinates, I am off by about two or three hundred on Chrome, FF and IE. So again, I am someone not getting the coordinates right, or there is just a better way to do this without specify such strict numbers across the div.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to use 10 separate images with half stars. Then everything will be achievable with 4 lines of CSS

HTML:

```
<div class="left_half"><img src="spacer.gif" width="16px" height="32px" onclick="rate( 5);"></div>
<div class="right_half"><img src="spacer.gif" width="16px" height="32px" onclick="rate(10);"></div>
<div class="left_half"><img src="spacer.gif" width="16px" height="32px" onclick="rate(15);"></div>
<div class="right_half"><img src="spacer.gif" width="16px" height="32px" onclick="rate(20);"></div>
<div class="left_half"><img src="spacer.gif" width="16px" height="32px" onclick="rate(25);"></div>
<div class="right_half"><img src="spacer.gif" width="16px" height="32px" onclick="rate(30);"></div>
<div class="left_half"><img src="spacer.gif" width="16px" height="32px" onclick="rate(35);"></div>
<div class="right_half"><img src="spacer.gif" width="16px" height="32px" onclick="rate(40);"></div>
<div class="left_half"><img src="spacer.gif" width="16px" height="32px" onclick="rate(45);"></div>
<div class="right_half"><img src="spacer.gif" width="16px" height="32px" onclick="rate(50);"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.left_half {
 background:url('left_half_empty.png');
}

.left_half:hover {
 background:url('left_half_full.png');
}

.right_half {
 background:url('right_half_empty.png');
}

.right_half:hover {
 background:url('right_half_full.png');
}
```

Comment: Indeed changing the css and html is one way to do it but I am trying to work with the css and html that was given to us and is in use in multiple places on the site. I don't want to rework everything if I don't have to but I realize it is an option.

Answer (score 0):

Split them in a transparant div for every rating. Much less code.